# Is possible to make watermark film with libav without decoding full video?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

Ther is a small png image and a video film.
I want to overlay this png image into video film and I did it by libavcodec.
The CPU loading of this overlay process is extermely high.
To reduce the performance impact, I have the png overlaid in 10 seconds and then copy stream from old file to new ones after 10 seconds.
The problem is, the video is ok before 10 seconds with png overlaid video. 
After 10 seconds, the video is stalled and begin to show abnormal green block at top of the screen.
I figure out the spspps maybe different between the original stream and the transcoded stream. Is this a root to cause the video stalled after 10 seconds?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is. Although you can insert SPS&PPS before every I-frame to support different encoding parameters and seeking, don't expect all players to support this feature.

Comment: One question before I post the answer...the image is like a logo or is just text?